# How to integrate my unity3d based game 's web build into facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I need a guide or a reference of publishing my game on facebook. 
Things done so far but no good :
 - >  creation of the web build of my game which yields two files viz . ( my_game.html and .unity3d binary file ) 
 - > hosting of this game on myserver (i have got the working link : www.mydomain.com/games/mygame.html )
 - >  creation of an app on my facebook id .
 - > substituting the blank canvas url with the url mentioned in step 2 .
 but Now What ....??

what i need is my friends could play my game as a facebook app just like say https://apps.facebook.com/candycrush/...
this page lets users to play candy crush game .

Answer (score 0):

First, compile Your App for WebPlayer.

You must register here: https://developers.facebook.com, also, You can get there FB-plugin for Your App.

Create Your FB app here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

In main preferences select "+Facebook application", and turn "Unity Integration Enabled:" on. Now, select url to Your app here: "Unity Binary URL:", it MUST be uploaded on `httpS:\\` server

Comment: i have done this ...it works with http:// though ...
But can you let me know how can i extend this... i mean get info from my app  and do all the stuffs like posting scores on wall , requests to friends ....etc....

Comment: You can do it with FB SDK. Read here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/ and here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/